# Is it possible to pass variable as parameter in javascript function?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, treeview, tree-nodes

I have this function:

```
 protected void mytv_SelectedNodeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    TreeView tv = sender as TreeView;
    var nid = tv.SelectedNode.Value;
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "anyname", "show(nid)", true);
}
```

As you can see, I have a variable nid that gets different value as 1,2,3 according to the treenode clicked.

Can i pass that nid variable value directly as a parameter to the javascript function as show(nid)?

If not what do i do?

My javascript function is as follows:

```
function show(nid) 
{

    if (nid == 4) {
        alert('testing');
    }
    else
     {
         alert('what???');
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try concatenating :

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "anyname", "show(" + nid + ")", true);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
//for string value
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "anyname", string.Format("show('{0}')", nid), true);
//for int value
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "anyname", string.Format("show({0})", nid), true);
```